# Viewing Code Coverage Results outside of Visual studio

Tags: c#, code-coverage, code-analysis, report

I've got some unit tests, and got some code coverage data. Now, I'd like to be able to view that code coverage data outside of visual studio, say in a web browser. But, when I export the code coverage to an xml file, I can't do anything with it. Are there readers out there for this? Do I have to write an xml parser and then display it how I want it (seems like a waste since visual studio already does this.) Seems kinda silly to have to take a screenshot of my code coverage results as my "report"
Suggestions?

Answer (score 14):

This tool https://github.com/danielpalme/ReportGenerator quickly generate Html reports from coverage file. Works quite well and does not require complex activities, can be easily included in the build process.

Answer (score 3):

There is this tool called Visual Coverage (https://github.com/jsargiot/visual-coverage). It takes a .coverage file as input and can export it to clover or html.

The page on github shows how to execute and if you're curious you can take a look at the code...

Comment: Be aware that visual-coverage doesn't output correct values for C++ projects

Answer (score 2):

You can use the tool NDepend and [visualize code coverage results](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#Coverage) imported from *NCover*, *dotCover* or *Visual Studio coverage*. The tool can show [code coverage vs. lines of code](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/treemap-visualization-of-code-metrics#Color) in a colored treemap. This feature is especially useful to browse at a glance which portion of code is well covered or not by tests.

[image: NDepend colored treemap code coverage vs. lines of code]

You can also write and apply continuously [code rules written over LINQ queries (CQLinq)](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL) like:

[From now, all types added or refactored should be 100% covered by tests](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_From_now,_all_types_added_or_refactored_should_be_100__covered_by_tests.html)

```
// <Name>From now, all types added or refactored should be 100% covered by tests</Name>
warnif count > 0 from t in JustMyCode.Types where

  // Match methods new or modified since Baseline for Comparison...
  (t.WasAdded() || t.CodeWasChanged()) &&

  // ...that are not 100% covered by tests
  t.PercentageCoverage < 100

  let methodsCulprit = t.Methods.Where(m => m.PercentageCoverage < 100)

select new { t, t.PercentageCoverage, methodsCulprit }
```

...or also:

- [Types that used to be 100% covered but not anymore](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Types_that_used_to_be_100__covered_but_not_anymore.html)
- [C.R.A.P method code metric](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_C.R.A.P_method_code_metric.html)
- [Complex methods partially covered by tests should be 100% covered](http://www.ndepend.com/DefaultRules/webframe.html?Q_Complex_methods_partially_covered_by_tests_should_be_100__covered.html)

The panel *Search by Coverage* can generate such Code Query over LINQ, and displays          instantly the matched code elements:

[image: Search methods by coverage]

Also, the tool can build a [HTML/javascript reports](http://www.ndepend.com/SampleReports.aspx) that will show *code rules violated* or *code queries results*.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use the tool of dotnet for generate the report in html

```
dotnet tool install -g dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool
```

```
reportgenerator
"-reports:Path\To\TestProject\TestResults\{guid}\coverage.cobertura.xml"
"-targetdir:coveragereport"
-reporttypes:Html
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-code-coverage?tabs=linux#generate-reports

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for the content of the exported XML, but I'd expect it contain your coverage data as a summary.

The usual thing to do with XML data like this if you want to see it in a web browser page is to convert it to HTML by writing and running a custom XSLT script.  This will presumably get you HTML text and tables containing your data.

If you want to see the coverage data as decorations imposed on the source code, I think  you have a much harder problem.

Answer (score 0):

Might help: you can open all the coverage data in the Code Coverage Results pane and copy&paste it to Excel...

Comment: This doesn't apply to Visual Studio Professional, where Code Coverage feature is not included

Comment: Was that a requirement?

Answer (score -1):

I use NCover to do all my code coverage and you have the ability to export the results quite easily